# SQL Server ODBC canonical date format to DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000

Lets say I have a datetime from my database, such as: `2011-10-24 00:00:00.000`. I would like to convert this into `24/10/2011`, but I can't find the native SQL Server way to do this, and I'd rather no do this in the code after I run my query.

I've tried doing something as follows ([as per the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx))

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2011-10-24 00:00:00.000', 103);
```

But that doesn't work out, my result is:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

I suspect this might be due to the decimal precision, or the time part of this, but I'm not sure how to go about this without resulting to some string-hacking-regex-replace nonsense (and I'd rather no do that, I might as well end up doing the conversion after the query if I do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read the manual correctly, you should be using stlye 120 "ODBC canonical" - no??

Try:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2011-10-24 00:00:00.000', 120);
```

Works on my machine :-) This gives you a SQL Server `DATETIME` to work with.

If you want to convert that further into `24/10/2011`, use a second `CONVERT` to convert into a `VARCHAR` string:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(datetime, '2011-10-24 00:00:00.000', 120), 103)
```

That gives me:

```
24/10/2011
```

Comment: Awesome answer, if I change varchar to 10 instead of 50, this won't cause issue?

Comment: @Incognito: no, that should be fine too - I just "default" to `varchar(50)` (so it can hold a GUID, too, for instance), but that's just my (bad?) habit ....

Comment: Looks good to me, I just wish there was a shorter way to get this that was also native to the convert feature.

Comment: @Incognito: SQL Server 2012 ("Denali") will feature a `Format` function .... maybe it's time to get upgraded soon!